# Using Meteor with Angular2/Typescript, how do I call an external web service from server-side code based on a client-side event?

Tags: meteor, typescript, angular, angular2-meteor

When the user adds a new entry in the client, I need to make a web service call from the server (the client-side code will not have access) and add some additional information to the data stored in MongoDB.
Trying to use the standard Meteor.methods/Meteor.call pattern does not seem to work.

Do I need to listen for the click event on the "Add" button on both the server and the client?
Should I raise a custom event on the client that the server reacts to?
Is there a proper way to make a direct call to a server-side method?
Most importantly, how do I keep TypeScript happy in all of this?

I am new to the TypeScript layer on top of Meteor and it is throwing me for loop. I have been generally following the Angular-Meteor tutorial for 2.0 but this sort of thing is not covered yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using angular2, Meteor and Typescript, what works is to chain the Meteor.methods.

First on the client, in response to a button click 
 ...
 Meteor.call('importCsv',id,function(error,result) {
 ...

In collections/methods folder or similar, I define the method as follows:

```
Meteor.methods({
 'importCsv': function(id) {
    console.log('importCsv method on client');
    Meteor.call('importCsvServer',id);

 }
```

});

In server/ folder, a file includes the method as follows

```
Meteor.methods({
'importCsvServer': function(id) {
```

....

In server/main.ts I import the collections/methods/filename. In client/app.ts I import the same thing. The client Meteor.call successfully calls the first method which then calls the second one in the server/ folder.

My goal is to have a bunch of processing on the server initiated by the client. When I had the function calls in the method defined in collections/methods imported into both the client and server, it resulted in compiler errors.

[Angular2-Meteor issue 74](https://github.com/Urigo/angular2-meteor/issues/74)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can call directly from the server to the web service in order to receive data. I am not so sure how you did for the `Meteor.methods/Meteor.call` and say it did not work. But basically, the idea is client will click the button and then button will trigger a method on the server. The server method then will call the web service and return the data.

Some example code could be:

```
Template['template'].events({
    'click .getData': function(event: any) {
        Meteor.call('serverMethod', function(err, res) {
            if (err) {alert(err);}
            else { ... }

        )
    }
});
```

The tricky part for new comer when calling the rest is you need to use `aysnc` calling in order to return the data to client. We normally make helper function for that

```
    public static get(url: string, headers: any): any {
        var httpCall  = Meteor.wrapAsync(HTTP.call);

        var result = httpCall('GET', url, {headers: headers});

        if (result.statusCode == 200) {
            try {
                var res = JSON.parse(result.content);

                return res;
            } catch(err) {
                return result.content;
            }   
        }

        return null;    
    }
```

And call the helper like this

```
public static serverMethod(username: string, password: string): any {
    var response = RestService.get(query.url, query.header); 
    return response;
}
```

This way, the `res` in the client code above will get the result.

I actually dropped the Angular 2 for the lack of documentation, but stay with Typescript for my system because I can wrap all the meteor call inside the Typescript class, as you can see in my example, `serverMethod` is in the typescript function format, not in meteor way like `Meteor.methods({....})`, which is really good for now

Typically, this is a class in my server folder

```
// server/rest.service.ts
declare var RestService: any;
RestService = class RestService {

    methodMap = {
        "getFromRest": RestService.get,
        "postToRest": RestService.post,
    };

    constructor() {
        var abstractService = new AbstractService();
        abstractService.registerMethod(this.getClassName(), this.methodMap);        
    }

    getClassName(): string {
        return this.constructor.toString().match(/\w+/g)[1];
    }

    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Helper methods
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public static get(url: string, headers: any): any {
        var httpCall  = Meteor.wrapAsync(HTTP.call);

        var result = httpCall('GET', url, {headers: headers});

        if (result.statusCode == 200) {
            try {
                var res = JSON.parse(result.content);

                return res;
            } catch(err) {
                return result.content;
            }   
        }

        return null;    
    }
```

I have a class to map the typescript service to the `meteor` method

```
// server/abstract.service.ts
declare var AbstractService: any;
AbstractService = class AbstractService {
    constructor() {}

    public registerMethod (scopeName: string, methodMap: {[key:string]:any}) {
        var scopeMap: {[key:string]: any} = {};

        for (var key in methodMap) {
            scopeMap[scopeName + '.' + key] = methodMap[key];
        }

        Meteor.methods(scopeMap);
    }
```

Comment: I not ready to give up on Angular2 just yet. I did find that the Meteor.methods/call technique works if I move the definition from the "server" to the "collections" folder. I would prefer to hide the type of details you have in your helper method from the client, so I am wondering where you place the "public static get"  function. (Trying to import a function from the "server" folder causes compile time errors.)