# How to call external rest api using metero HTTP module

Tags: meteor, angular2-components

I am currently new to ***Meteor*** and **Angular2** and I built an application with same.

I want to make *External API* call inside Meteor Server using Meteor HTTP Module.

Could you please give an example code in "**Typescript**" how to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I Upvoted this question as this includes something interesting regarding HTTP External API Call via Typescript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`HTTP.call()`](https://docs.meteor.com/api/http.html#HTTP-call) for external invoking API. You can call both `Get` and `post` requests with this. See the documentation link for details.

Here is a simple example

```
HTTP.call('POST', 'http://api.twitter.com/xyz', {
  data: { some: 'json', stuff: 1 }
}, () => (error, result) {
  if (!error) {
    Session.set('twizzled', true);
  }
});
```

Comment: Above example is in js, but i'm looking for an example in typescript as i'm using Angular2 and meteor...thanks!

Comment: sorry! I'm not familiar with angular 2. I used HTTP.call in server end, that's why plain js worked for me

Comment: @hanumanthraju try this code in your server main.ts . this is the same way we do in angular 2 meteor. it will work

Comment: @AmitKumar this code is absolutely okay with server side, but he is perhaps trying to make http calls from front end, not sure though

Comment: @mostafizrahman, i'm try make above http call from meteor server.

Comment: @AmitKumar, when put the above code in main.ts getting some typescript error.

Thanks for your suggestion.

I tried below Thai Tran's example code with some modification, it's worked for me.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34503400/using-meteor-with-angular2-typescript-how-do-i-call-an-external-web-service-fro/34503505#34503505

Thanks! Thai Tran